# php Yii Nested json array

Tags: php, json, yii

First code:
          $result=ResPlaces::model()->findall($criteria);

```
         /*foreach($result as $value)
     {
        $model_name=ResRegistration::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$value->user_id));
        $model_image=ResImages::model()->findByAttributes(array('place_id'=>$value->id),array('limit'=>'1'));


     }*/

     }
      echo CJSON::encode($result);
```

?>

i need to add  `model_name->company_name   &  $model_image->image`
to my  echo   json array

Comment: Are these both set up as a relation in your ResPlaces model?

Comment: i update my question  yes ( have relation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load the relations within the findAll so you don't need the foreach.

```
ResPlaces::model()->with('ResRegistration', 'ResImages')->together()->findAll($criteria);
```

For `ResRegistration` and `ResImages` use the relation names as defined in your model.
If you don't need all fields of these relations, you can specify a `select` in your $criteria.

See the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail) for more info.

edit: I am not quite sure, why you cannot use relation. However you will need a loop, like you already have. Here is how you do it without relations:

First add the fields you want to use to your model. In this case

```
class ResPlaces extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $name; // check that these do not collide with your models db fields
    public $image;

    [...]
}
```

In your controller do the loop like you did before:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{

    $result[$key]->name = ResRegistration::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $value->user_id));

    // findByAttributes returns only one record, so you don't need the limit here
    // if you want multiple records, you have to use findAllByAttributes
    $result[$key]->image = ResImages::model()->findByAttributes(array('place_id' => $value->id), array('limit' => '1'));
}
```

That should do it. However I wouldn't recommend this way, because you have lots of additional database requests. If your `$result` is populated with say 100 records, you have in sum 200 additional queries which are not nessassary with a relation.

Note also that if you need these two other fields more often, it may be better to put these two queries which are now in the controller in your model. The `afterFind()` would be the right place.

Comment: ResRegistration has id   and  ResPlaces has user_id                     i use                                                              return array('company_name'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ResRegistration', 'id'),     to make relation but $result don't show ResRegistration information

Comment: Well what is the output then? Do a var_dump. Also posting your models may help.

Comment: chris i can't make yii relation  so from my question can you help me to make all output in one json array?

Comment: thx for your full reply i think you help me but i need final step  echo  CJSON::encode($result);   which have all variables from $result/$result[$key]->name/$result[$key]->image        i need them in one json echo